# ığ character like this are displaying bold

Tags: html, css, saas

I have the webpage in üüşçöğı with these characters. I see few of them are displaying in bold.How to resolve it[image]

```
<p style="text-align: right;"><a href="#" target="_blank">Daha fazlasını öğrenin</a></p>

 body {
    font-family: "Proxima Nova",Arial,sans-serif;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}
```

Comment: Please share some code. How can we help you without it?

Comment: why balise <a> in <p> ? you can put p , a{ font-weight: normal ; }

Comment: Is your encdoing UTF-8? If so, try using `&#287;` instead of the bold character in your example. If that works, look up the numeric character reference for the other characters that are coming up bold and replace those as well.